# a regex or function to extract all the parameters passed to a function

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to find the passed parameter to a function

say i already have hello as function and i have a STRING as following

```
hello(1,'434','hello,word',"h,g",{a:'b,u', l : { "sk" : "list", bk : 'u,93' }, c : 9},true)
```

Then upon that regex or function i should be able to find following 6 strings

```
'1'
'"434"'
'"hello,world"'
'"h,g"'
'{"a":"b,u","l":{"sk":"list","bk": "u,93"},"c":9}'
'true'
```

Comment: yes that should be there, i will update the question

Comment: It would probably be easier to write a tokenizer, which goes through the string character-by-character. A regular expression able to parse something like this would be very complicated and error-prone.

Comment: it will be very difficult to manage nested patterns

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen any example or any suitable link

Answer (score 1):

As per urs question you can do it like this:

```
x =Hello(1,'434','hello,word',"h,g",{a:'b,u', l : { "sk" : "list", bk : 'u,93' }, c : 9},true);

function Hello() {
    for (i = 0; i <arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]) 
    }

}
```

You can take help of [argument object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a string then you might have to escape the double quotes first to result like

```
var x = "hello(1,'434','hello,word',\"h,g\",{a:'b,u', l : { \"sk\" : \"list\", bk : 'u,93' }, c : 9},true)";
```

and then you may invoke it like

```
Function(x)();
```

and in the `hello` function you should iterate over the arguments object's properties like

```
function hello(){
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, prop => console.log(prop));
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure to sort that regex out would be less user friendly but of course doable.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround. It may be error-prone, but it should be faster than the `eval` solutions.

```
var extractParameters = function(str){
  var ar = [];
    if(typeof str === 'string' && str.length){
        var chars = str.split(','), cl = chars.length;
        var pushInto = function(n){
            try {
                ar.push(JSON.parse(chars[n]));
            } catch(er){
                ar.push(undefined);
            }
        };
        for(var di, si, eg, fg, n = 0; n < cl; n++){
            eg = chars[n].charAt(0);
            fg = chars[n].charAt(chars[n].length - 1);
            if(eg === fg && (eg === '"' || eg === "'")){
                chars[n] = "\"" + chars[n].substring(1, chars[n].length - 1) + "\"";
            }
            di = chars[n].indexOf('"');
            si = chars[n].indexOf("'");
            if(((si === -1) && (di === -1)) || (eg === fg && (eg === '"' || eg === "'")) ||
                 (chars[n].charAt(0) === "{" && chars[n].charAt(chars[n].length-1) === "}" && (chars[n].match(/\{/g).length === chars[n].match(/\}/g).length))){
                pushInto(n);
            } else if(n < (cl-1)) {
                chars[n] = chars[n] + ','+ chars[n+1];
                chars.splice(n+1,1);
                n--;
                cl--;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return ar;
};
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jv0328tp/16/